# Google Drive list method doesn't list files created recently

Tags: google-drive-api

I've developed an extension for Google Chrome that HEAVILY relies on Google Drive API (the extension is LBTimer, available in Google Chrome web store), to store data in the appfolder, using XMLHttpRequests

Since May, 13th 2015 I'm finding a problem when using the [list method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).
If I programmatically create a file in the appfolder, I receive the response: 200 OK and the file created. If then I use the list method to list the files in the appfolder, the file just created is not listed. It happened with several files yesterday. This morning, the files were listed normally, but with any file I create today it happens the same (correctly created but not listed).

Three screens follow: the 1st one is creating a test file in the appfolder using the extension's code. the image shows the server response (200 OK, file created). The second screen shows the list request (list all files whose title contains 'test', it should include the file just created). The third screen shows the response from the server (an empty items list).

[image: The test file is successfully created]

[image: The files.list request responds 200 OK, but...]

[image: No file is listed. And it has just been created!]

There is a way to get them listed: If I create a file, it returns (among other data) the file Id. If I make a simple GET request for that Id, then it is listed from then on.

All other methods are working as expected (as usual), but the list method is giving me this problem since yesterday. Since there was no change in the extension's code, I assume there must have been a change in the API code.

Comment: paste some code and the http traces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was a caching issue in Google Drive, which has been resolved as of May 15th 2015: [Google Drive developers community post](https://plus.google.com/100071448032466638407/posts/jbuM14eYs9b)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I noticed the same issue from today. I'm using Google Drive Java API to create files in hidden Application data folder (appfolder). Files are created correctly, but "Hidden data size" i 0. I noticed that my files appears after few hours! I reported this issue to Google several hours ago by Google Developers Console, but the issue still occurs. I think more users should do this to get their attention to this critical issue.